# Upgrade laravel from 5.1 to 5.8 and artisan commands are not working in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have a project which is developed in laravel 5.1 now which client wants some updates where he want to upgrade laravel version to 5.8 but and to add some new functionality but this is 2nd issue 1st issue this terminal is throwing the error of `each` when run `php srtisan`

```
C:\xampp\zerodocs>php artisan


  [ErrorException]
  The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP `each()` function was deprecated in PHP 7.2.  It seems you are using PHP 7.2 or higher. You will need to follow the upgrade guides and use composer to upgrade from Laravel 5.1 to 5.8.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade

Or, you will need switch to a compatible PHP version (e.g., PHP >= 5.5.9 as mentioned in the documentation for Laravel 5.1) to use the application.

Comment: i am using  PHP/5.6.30 version

Comment: how can i get rid of this each()

Comment: when i use phpinfo() it shows 5.6 but when i use php -v in console it shows 7.1 version

Comment: Assuming you have both PHP versions installed, you should be able to use the full path `/path/to/php5.6/php artisan...` if you can determine what it that path is.  Unfortunately, I cannot tell you where that will be in xampp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017359/showing-two-different-php-versions-in-command-line

can you check this may be it is more specific question

Comment: you answer worked but do i need every-time to pass the complete path of php

Comment: So then try command `C:/xampp/php/php artisan down` and see if you get a maintenance mode response (in your project directory).

Comment: I'm guessing the other PHP version is stored in your Windows path variable.  You would need to update the path variable accordingly to point to the correct PHP installation if you don't want to have to use the whole path.